# SQL Counter Increment/Decrement Synchronization

Tags: sql, jdbc, synchronization, counter

Counters Table (SQL database table)

```
CounterID     |CounterValue
1             |5
2             |3
```

I have multiple clients accessing/modifying (increment & decrement) these counters via JDBC. What is the best way to handle the counters synchronously.

Currently clients select the counter value first, then increment it and update the value.But the problem is if two clients do select the same value before the other update the counter value.

Please advice.
Thanks.

Comment: If your database has sequences (generators), then you should consider using those instead.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel In this case, using db2 in AS400. Add/Remove counters will happen often, and I don't have the authority to create a new sequence for every counter.

Answer (score 1):

The following will ensure that each call gets a unique counter value.
Run this in an autonomous transaction:

```
While (true) do
  SELECT CounterValue into cv FROM CountersTable WHERE CounterID = 1;
  UPDATE countertable SET CounterValue = cv+1 WHERE CounterID = 1 and CounterValue = cv;
  IF (rows updated > 0) THEN
     COMMIT;
     EXIT LOOP; --No one else modified the CounterValue
  END IF
End do;
```

Comment: I'm using JDBC. As I understand you are suggesting to use transactions. Thanks, I'm looking for other alternatives as well. (because, Implementing transaction based updating in current system is a lot of work.)

Comment: If you are using autocommit then you can just remove the commit from my answer.